# Error when using plugin QuickCache with plugin Mobile Smart ?

Tags: plugins, themes

When I using 2 theme(`theme_1 for PC, theme_2 for mobile`), when run as PC is theme is `theme_1`, but when run as mobile is theme is `theme_1`, I think this error plugin `Quick Cache`, When I setting plugin Quick Cache, I find this row:

[image: Quick Cache]

```
=> How to fix this row to when run as mobile is theme_2, when run as PC is theme_1
```